# Handling special characters in VARCHAR2 while converting it to json

Tags: json, plsql

I have the following `pl/sql`  block where in I am converting a `VARCHAR2` type into json. I am facing an issue when the `VARCHAR2` type consists of  a special character like `/` the json parser throws an exception:

```
DECLARE
oj json := json('{a/b:xy})');
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line(oj.TO_CHAR());
END;`enter code here`

ORA-20100: JSON Scanner exception @ line: 1 column: 5 - Unexpected char: /
ORA-06512: at "PARIS.JSON_PARSER", line 87
ORA-06512: at "PARIS.JSON_PARSER", line 447
ORA-06512: at "PARIS.JSON_PARSER", line 646
ORA-06512: at "PARIS.JSON", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Can this be handled?

Answer (score 1):

Your json can't be parsed

Try to send a valid JSON and it'll work

```
json('{"a/b": "xy"}')
```